# Javascript for track total number of tags (<div>) in a page by the tag ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tags

i'm looking of a code which return me total number of a tags base on the same tag ID ,
so like in a page  i have 3  tags with ID="my" so i need js return me 3 divs.
Ex. Code

```
<div id="my">HI</div>
<div id="my">HI</div>
<div id="my">HI</div>
```

and i want the js access form a .js file.

actuly the `<div id="my">HI</div>` also echo from the .js ..
if a user add the .js 10 times !
so the tags `<div id="my">HI</div>` but i need after 2 time echo the tags stop echo.
only 2 time use JS. 
so if find the total number of tags on the page its help to stop echo after 2 echo use js if its possible !!
its really important for me ..
Thanks

Comment: duplicate ids....that is invalid html. ids should be unique.

Comment: use class instead of ids

Comment: we can use class .. or anything  similar unique for stop write after 2 time done

Comment: yes but what is the ja code for track the total number of class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use class.

var numItems = $('.my').length

```
<div class="my">HI</div>
<div class="my">HI</div>
<div class="my">HI</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat id, that is invalid html, use class instead.

```
<div class="my">HI</div>
<div class="my">HI</div>
<div class="my">HI</div>
```

and then use this selector:

```
$("div .my").length; // means DIV tags having class 'my'
```

You can learn more about selectors here:http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/